# Is it possible to use Jade mixin argument as a html tag

Tags: javascript, html, pug

For inststance I need a mixin to wrap any text in defferent HTML elements.

```
mixin doWrap(myText, myWrapper)
    if myWrapper
        myWrapper= myText
    else
        div= myText
```

So this mixin **pseudocode** can clarify what I need: when specific wrapper is set, text `myText` must be wrapped in it, but if there is no wrapper parameter specified, mixin must use some default HTML element as a wrapper.

So is it possible in Jade to pass a string mixin argument and use the argument as HTML tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, so it maybe useful for somebody. 
Tag interpolation can be achieved by using the following code:

```
#{some_tag}
```

So my previous example can be modified like this:

```
mixin doWrap(myText, myWrapper)
    if myWrapper
        #{myWrapper}= myText
    else
        div= myText
```

I haven't found this information in official Jade docs, but here is a [link to an issue](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/954) about it on github